# how to make Lazy Vertical Staggered Grid's item wrap content

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, staggered-gridview, staggeredgridlayout

I want my Lazy Vertical Staggered Grid's items to take size of it's content.
Contents are of different size.

I want all the item of Lazy Vertical Staggered Grid to display the full text but it's not showing the full text

```
LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
columns = StaggeredGridCells.Adaptive(60.dp),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(12.dp),
    verticalItemSpacing = 8.dp,
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(14.dp),
    content = {
        items(state.itemList){item->
        ElevatedCard(shape = AbsoluteRoundedCornerShape(
        topLeft = 16.dp, bottomRight = 16.dp),
        modifier = Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Max)
        ) {
         Column(
           modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(8.dp)
        ) {

         Image(
         imageVector = item.icon,
         contentDescription = null,
         colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseSurface),
          modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .aspectRatio(4f)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)),
            )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))

        Text(
        text = item.name,
        maxLines = 1,
        fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold,
        modifier = Modifier
             .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)   
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))

        Text(
        text = item.pageUrl,
        maxLines = 1,
        fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
        fontSize = 12.sp,
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
        )                   
    }
}
```

[Output I got.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfBVO.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

`LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid` items are supposed to be the same width but different heights and arranged vertically. If you want different widths, then you can use `LazyHorizontalStaggeredGrid`, but then items will be arranged horizontally. What are are trying to achieve can be done with a [FlowRow](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/flow) instead. Note that the top icon can't have `aspectRatio` and `fillMaxWidth`, because increasing width will make it also increase in height.

[image]

```
    FlowRow(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(14.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
    ) {
        itemList.forEach { item ->
            ElevatedCard(
                shape = AbsoluteRoundedCornerShape(
                    topLeft = 16.dp, bottomRight = 16.dp
                ),
                modifier = Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Max),
            ) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(8.dp)
                ) {

                    Image(
                        imageVector = item.icon,
                        contentDescription = null,
                        colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseSurface),
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            //.aspectRatio(4f)
                            .height(12.dp)
                            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)),
                    )

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))

                    Text(
                        text = item.name,
                        maxLines = 1,
                        fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                    )

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))

                    Text(
                        text = item.pageUrl,
                        maxLines = 1,
                        fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                        fontSize = 12.sp,
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you @JanItor

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing that you are trying to achieve does not fit the concept of `LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid`. See the sample image for `LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid` below:

[image: http://joebirch.co/android/exploring-lazy-staggered-grids-in-jetpack-compose/]

As you can see, the items **width** is **fixed**, but the **height** adjusts depending on the length of the content inside the item. So you can't really set the item width to wrap content. The only thing you could do is to play around with the `StaggeredGridCells` values. You can increase the [minSize](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/staggeredgrid/StaggeredGridCells.Adaptive) value in `StaggeredGridCells.Adaptive(60.dp)` to increase the item width.

Even if you were able to set the width to wrap content, you should consider that if a user sets the system font size on their phone to very large, it would happen that the whole layout becomes a single column.

So my proposed workaround is, if you really want to use a `LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid`, increase the min width value

```
StaggeredGridCells.Adaptive(100.dp)
```

and then configure the title Text to ellipsize:

```
Text(
    text = item.name,
    maxLines = 1,
    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
    fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
    fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold,
    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
)
```

As a possible alternative, please check out the [`FlowLayout`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/flow) Composables. There, you can set each item width to `wrapContentWidth()`.